# Place a draggable object between two droppable targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create a drag and drop that allows the draggable object to be dropped in between two droppable targets. Both droppable targets have to receive and accept the draggable object simultaneously and update their "Dropped!" status.

I have made it work, but it's a little buggy. You have to move and reposition the object between the two drop targets a few times before they show the dropped status.

This is the result I want:

[image]

My Attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lynb2s6/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px;}
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  #droppablea { width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppablea" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Object</p>
</div>


<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="droppablea" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the tolerance of the droppables to touch

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance

```
$( "#droppablea" ).droppable({
  tolerance: "touch",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  tolerance: "touch",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
      .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```